# EF Core - Oracle Take and Skip

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, skip, take

How to use Skip and Take with Oracle and EF Core?

This query...

```
var q = db.Set<T>()
    .FilterBy(filtri)
    .Skip(0)
    .Take(10);
```

...Generates this wrong query (ora-00933 sql command not properly ended):

```
DECLARE 
l_sql     varchar2(32767);
l_cur     pls_integer;
l_execute pls_integer;

BEGIN
l_cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
l_sql := 'SELECT "w"."REQUESTNUM", ..."
FROM "MP2"."WOREQ" "w"
WHERE (("w"."SITEID" = ''TESTCC'') AND ("w"."TASKNUM" = ''AAAQ''))
OFFSET :p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT :p_1 ROWS ONLY';
dbms_sql.parse(l_cur, l_sql, dbms_sql.native);
dbms_sql.bind_variable(l_cur, ':p_0', 0);
dbms_sql.bind_variable(l_cur, ':p_1', 10);
l_execute:= dbms_sql.execute(l_cur);
dbms_sql.return_result(l_cur);
END;
```

Without Skip and Take:

```
SELECT "w"."REQUESTNUM", ... 
FROM "MP2"."WOREQ" "w"
WHERE (("w"."SITEID" = 'TESTCC') AND ("w"."TASKNUM" = 'AAAQ'))
```

I'm using Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore nuget package.

Comment: What version of Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore are you using? I'm using Skip and Take in many queries and don't have this issue on 6.21.90

Comment: `OFFSET ... FETCH NEXT ... ROWS ...` was introduced in Oracle 12. If you are using Oracle 11 or earlier then of course it will not work as you are using unsupported syntax. You should check if there are compatibility options for earlier versions. Additionally, you do not specify an `ORDER BY` clause so you will get a randomly ordered result set and then skip X rows and take the next Y and then the next time you do it the rows might not be in the same order so you would get a different set of rows.

Comment: @Luke I'm using 6.21.90, too. 
Are you working with Oracle 12 as suggested by MT0?

Comment: @MT0 Thanks, I will check.
Order by is not present because the query is for test purpose.

Comment: I wondered about DB version as well. I'm on 19c. Definitely sounds like it could be your issue.

Comment: @Luke i realized I'm on 11g :(

Comment: SOLUTION: I remembered that i used a particular Extension method for other sql sintax problem. This resolved my problem for Oracle 11:

                optionsBuilder
                    .UseOracle(MyConnectionString,
                        x => x.UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11")
                    );